# Overflow hidden doesn't work on several pages

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow

overflow-x: hidden doesn't work for some reason on some pages.
I have a slide-in menu which I hide with overflow-x hidden globally on my WP site.
However on this and several other pages(please check only mob version)  https://kudatoday.kz/alcogol/  it doesn't hide my menu.(On main page it does).

Do you have any advise? "!important" didn't help.
I really appreciate your help.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: please open F12 and see if any style override your style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `overflow-y` on the `id` page-container. remove it or change it to `overflow-x`.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Love u